# magmi no attribute_set defined

Tags: php, magento, export, magmi

We are consistently getting the no attribute_set defined message when attempting to upload a variety of CSV files to Magento via Magmi.  At this point we are firmly embedded in the "pulling our hair out" stage! :-))

Our attribute set has been defined in Magento (although we have also tried using default) and we have tried customs CSV files and CSV files generated moments earlier using Data Profile export and in all cases we receive this same error message.

We have tried embedding all fields in quotes, without quotes, headers in quotes, without quotes etc etc etc. We have tried files with only basic field completed also to no avail.  We have installed versions of magmi on different servers which again yields the same error message.

We would be unbelievably grateful for some insight as to what we are doing wrong.  I should also point out that we have used Magmi successfully in the distant past so the mystery is even bigger!

A sample file can be supplied (the CSV shows tier pricing however we have also tried the same with no tier pricing and the same result is returned no attribute_set defined).

Comment: I should also have mentioned we are on Magento CE 1.7.0.2

Comment: You should post a snippet of your CSV including the headers.

Comment: please help if you solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Check name in your Magento Admin Panel. Names must be the same, in .csv file and Panel !

For example "default" and "**default**" , NO Default in Magento Admin Panel!